# Delete all occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: c, string, pointers

The function receives a string and a substring and should delete all occurrences of that substring in the string. 
For example,

```
string = hello world
substring = hello
```

The function should print just "`world`"

I should point out that **I must solve this only using pointers**.

I've try this, but it only deletes the occurrences of the first letter of the substring.

```
char* del_all_substr(char *pstr, char *psub){

    char *pr = pstr;
    char *pw = pstr;

    while (*pr){
        for (int i = 0; i <strlen(psub);i++) {
            *pw = *pr++;
            pw += (*pw != *(psub+i));
        }
        *pw = '\0';
    }
}
```

```
int main_tp06(int argc, const char *argv[]){

    char str[] = "hello world";
    char sub[] = "hello";

    del_all_substr(str,sub);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be allowed to use `strlen`, how about `strcmp`?

Comment: `del_all_substr()` should return a `char *`, yet it doesn't.

Comment: @bolov I call it that because we have a different .c file for each class at university, don't worry, it works

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so... ```strcmp(str,sub)``` and do the same as shown?

Comment: If `strcmp(pstr, psub) == 0` then [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) from `pstr + strlen(psub)` to `pstr`. Then `++pstr` until `*pstr == '\0'`.

Comment: Special case you need to handle: `strlen(pstr) < strlen(psub)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `strcmp` doesn't tell you if one string is a prefix of the other, which is what you'd need here.

Comment: Slight update: You need to use [`strncmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) and not `strcmp`. More specifically `strncmp(pstr, psub, strlen(psub))`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `strstr` repeatedly to find all occurrences of the string. For example consider this string `"Hello world, Hello world"`, and say that we want to move all occurrences of `"Hello"` from the string. You can use `strstr` to find the first instance of `"Hello"`, after that you can overwrite it by moving everything in the string back using memmove (make sure you move the nul terminator as well), repeat again and again until `strstr` returns no matches. You could also avoid this approach by instead allocating your own string that is at least `strlen(pstr)` bytes long and then copying data from `pstr` byte by byte and not copying the bytes that match `psub`